# Python list in double index How to split it ety.origin list

Tags: python, list, indexing, split

Hi Everyone I have python to find origin of a word so I got result in list's How I want it to separate or split it with comma (,).

```
origin=ety.origins(wordtodo)
print(origin)
>>[Word(how, Middle English (1100-1500) [enm]), Word(haugr, Old Norse [non])]
```

in  the result I want text inside (...) braket's and store into different variable
e.g.

```
forigin=(how, Middle English (1100-1500) [enm])
```

and

```
sorigin=(haugr, Old Norse [non])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
forigin = repr(origin[0])[4:]
sorigin = repr(origin[1])[4:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Author of `ety` here

`ety.origins` returns a list of [`Word`](https://github.com/jmsv/ety-python/blob/master/ety/word.py) objects.

Get properties of a `Word` with specific fields `.word` and `.language`, or use `.pretty` to get a string version of the word/language in format `{word} ({lang})` - e.g. `'how (Middle English (1100-1500))'`